# Why is my System.out.println not executing?

Tags: java

I cant figure out why this wont execute. Any ideas? Is my syntax wrong or did I not initialize count correctly?

Here's the code:

```
int product = 0, count=0;
while (product < 2500){
    product *= 5;
    count++;
}
    System.out.println(product);
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the state of `product` at each iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
product = 0
```

then you multiply it by 5

```
product *= 5;
```

`0 times 5 is still 0` so

```
while (product < 2500){
```

will always be true. consider setting

```
product = 1
```

initially so that it grows enough to exit the while loop and print at some point.

Comment: So basically right now it's considered an infinite loop, if i understand correctly?

Comment: yes if you don't change product to a positive value when you initialise it it always stays 0 and never leaves the loop

Answer (score 1):

product = 0;

//Your  are initialising your product variable with value = 0;

Then you keep on multiplying the product with 5, which will be zero only, so while loop will not hault.

so initialise product with some positive value.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **infinite loop**.

```
int product = 0, count=0;
while (product < 2500){
    product = 0 * 5;   // product is always 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above looks to have a logic error. It will never stop because the product value is never going to be greater than 0, therefore it will never exit the loop.

If you want to print the product every time it gets multiplied add the product print out line in the loop:

```
`while (product < 2500){
  product *= 5;
  count+= 1;
  System.out.println(product);
 }`
```

Keep in mind that the above code will never print anything but zero because product is never being changed since X * 0 = 0. Hope this makes sense! Happy coding!